# How to enable windows authentication on iis 8 on a Win2k12 machine using cmd

Tags: windows, model-view-controller, cmd, windows-server-2012

How to enable windows authentication on iis 8 on a Win2k12 machine using cmd ? I am running and MVC website on a server and not able to access it from the client with Error : 500 Internal Server error

Read this article but it doesn't work on Win2k12 machine http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IIS8, you need to specify the website's name within the command, for example:

```
appcmd set config "Default Web Site" /section:windowsAuthentication /enabled:true
```

Source: [Appcmd.exe (IIS 8) reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635852.aspx).

Comment: Get this error :  'appcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Yeah, you need to run appcmd in `%windir%\system32\inetsrv`. Just do `cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv` first.

Comment: "Default Web Site" . Is this required. Can it be optional

Comment: No, that's just an example; it's whatever the actual name of the site is. Here's a screenshot from my IIS8 instance: http://i.imgur.com/c1dW83J.png